# You cannot combine custom titles or other title features

Tags: android

This is just killing me.  I am not manipulating the feature title anywhere so Im not sure why I keep getting this error.  It errors at  `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);` or `getActionBar()` if I remove the previous line.

```
03-13 02:51:37.268: E/AndroidRuntime(7211): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.super64/com.super64.activities.events.EventActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
```

**EventActivity.java**

```
public class EventActivity extends BaseEventActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_container);
    }
```

**BaseEventActivity.java**

```
public class BaseEventActivity extends BaseActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
            ViewHelper.initTabs(getActionBar(), this);
        }
```

**themes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="ExposureTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/app_background_image</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/app_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ExposureActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ExposureActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">#f8f8f8</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't we use a Translucent system bars with and ActionBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746943/why-cant-we-use-a-translucent-system-bars-with-and-actionbar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to move this setContentView to the top, and it worked????????????

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_container);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: You should still do it after the call to super though.

Comment: Super contains the actionbar logic