# How to match the menu bar/notification bar color match application

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have an Android app which allows the user to change the color of a background based on the selection they choose.

This is the line that changes the color:

```
appBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(inRed, inGreen, inBlue));
```

How do I also change the menu bar color as well the notification bar to change to that color of the user's choice?

I know it's only possible in KitKat but can someone point me to the way...

Answer (score 0):

If you would like an effect like the image below, have a look here:
[Why can't we use a Translucent system bars with and ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746943/why-cant-we-use-a-translucent-system-bars-with-and-actionbar)

As you can see, the background color can be changed programatically (so it's not defined in the xml).

[image]