# Android Lollipop transparent statusbar

Tags: android, navigation, statusbar, drawer

My problem is easy but I need some help 
I have a MainActivity, several Fragments and NavigationDrawer. I also use a **Appcompat v7 
NavigationDrawer** is shown behind the statusbar for what I use **ScrimInsetsLayout**. 
In styles I have colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark(parent is Theme.Appcompat)

In main activity I use **setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)** to show Drawer in statusbar. So now I have colorPrimaryDark statusbar color and NavigationDrawer in statusbar

Now I created a new Fragment and I need to disable colorPrimaryDark color and make statusbar real transparent

As I said before, setting color to transparent makes it colorPrimaryDark with drawer shown

Setting it to any other color "hides" drawer.

Thanks

**Screenshots:**

[image: Screen1] [image: Screen1] [image: Screen1]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The <strike>transparent</strike> translucent status bar is available from API 19, create a new `values-v19` folder and a `styles.xml` inside it then update your `BaseAppTheme` like this:

```
<!-- Base application theme for v19. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

But, this would make your UI use the space behind `StatusBar`, so I would suggest adding an extra `TOP padding`, of 25dp (researched and found every API uses 25dp as `StatusBar` height even in `landscape` mode), for devices > API19

Comment: Thanks for a fast reply. I have tried this also, but I still have colorPrimaryDark behind it. So I have a statusbar color even darker then colorPrimaryDark

Comment: If you are trying to make a replica of iOS app, then first go through what you can/cannot have in Android. Complete transparent StatusBar is not possible in Android. http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#UI

Comment: No, my goal is Translucent statusbar, I understand that transparent is not possible. When I make iTtranslucent it is not actually translucent. Feels like I have colorPrimaryDark behind the translucent statusbar. And one more point. If I don't use setStatusBarColor I have translucent:)

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what you have and what you desire

Comment: http://imgur.com/AOJFL8C
http://imgur.com/uUCXcBt
http://imgur.com/ATPEXfg now I have pink statusbar. I want to keep it in "Friends" fragment and make translucent in profile fragment

Comment: Okay, they you can do this programmatically while switching fragments, use code given here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19792838/3485152